# Android.Gradle: Autoincrement Versoin Name before deploy

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle2 4.2
My app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 25
        versionName "1.2.25"

    }
}
```

My steps for deploy `apk` to Fabric (Beta by CrashLytics)

1. Manually increment **versionCode** and **verionName**. In this example: versionCode **26** and versionName "**1.2.26**"
2. Create distributive (`apk`) and deploy to `CrashLytics` by command:

   *gradlew assembleDebug crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug*

And as result my `apk` success deploy to Fabric with versionName = "**1.2.26**"

OK. It's work fine.

But I need to automatically increment *versionCode* and *versionName* **BEFORE** deploy to Fabric.
To do this I need to write custom `Gradle` task. Does my approach correct?